# Как получить размер файла в json массиве android?

Tags: android, массивы, json

У меня есть массив в котором находятся файлы конвертированные в base64. И вот у меня возникла необходимость получить размер каждого файла отдельно, но я так и не понял как это сделать. Вот как я получаю отдельный элемент:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
JsonObject object = array.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
movieList.add(new FileList(String.valueOf(object.get("filename")), String.valueOf(object.getAsDouble())));
}
```

и дальше я этот элемент массива добавляю в список. Но я не могу понять как получить размер этого элемента, в байтах, килобайтах или мегабайтах. Хоть в чем-то. Видел кучу способов как получить размер элемента JSONObject но у меня ведь не такой объект. Возможно можно как-то перегнать один вид объекта в другой но мне кажется это не очень хорошая идея.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так и не получив ответа, я сделал так как знаю, но не уверен что это правильное решение:

```
Integer data = object.get("data").toString().getBytes().length / 1024;
```

эта переменная равна количеству символов которые необходимы чтобы отобразить содержимое элемента массива. Потом после получения этого количества я делю число на 1024 и получаю размер файла в кб. Не уверен что это правильно, но вроде что-то выводит. Вот есть [ссылка](https://www.pixelstech.net/article/1427944920-String-length%28%29-vs-String-getBytes%28%29-length-in-Java), может кому поможет.